# Adding image to gallery in Android

Tags: android, image, broadcast

I have an app which does two things :

- it captures photo by camera app and saves it to gallery - and this works
- generates .gif out of images and saves it in `ExternalStoragePublicDirectory` - and this doesn't work

This is the method I am using to add file to gallery :

```
public static void galleryAddPic(Context context, String currentPhotoPath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

I have read somewhere that this doesn't work on Android Api 19, can anybody confirm? 
Is there any better solution for adding picture to gallery than my above method? 
Cheers

Comment: "generates .gif out of images and saves it in ExternalStoragePublicDirectory - and this doesn't work" What do you mean ? Your problem is storing the .gif or adding it to the Gallery ?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I mean I am taking all the pictures from app (stored in sdcard) and generate .gif out of it. Then I save this .gif to the sdcard folder "Pictures". I should see it in Windows Explorer and in Gallery.

Comment: Weird thing, now when I tested it works and shows in the Windows Explorer. It sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: You should take a look at the `MediaScanner` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html, the files are not visible immediately. take a look at this : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code For that

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```